# Angular 2 Role based navigation on same path

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular, angular2-routing

I've a small question regarding Angular 2 router using version `3.0.0-rc.1` I want to navigate to different home component based on user role such as AdminComponent or UserComponent. Can anyone please help in modifying below routes so that I can achieve the desired functionality?

```
{path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},  // <--- This redirects to '/' in case user is logged in
{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,               
  canActivate: [AuthGuardService],  // <--- Check if user is logged in, else redirect to login
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: AdminComponent  // <--- Want to navigate here if user role is 'admin'
    },
    {
      path: '',
      component: UserComponent  // <--- Want to navigate here if user role is 'user'
    }
  ]
}
```

AuthGuardService.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
import {AuthService} from "./auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      return true;
    }

    // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
    this.authService.redirectUrl = state.url;

    // Navigate to the login page with extras
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

AuthService.ts

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  redirectUrl: string;

  logout() {
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return localStorage.getItem('token') !== null;
  }

  isAdmin() {
    return localStorage.getItem('role') === 'admin';
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: @Dmitry no luck yet

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by below way.

```js
{path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},  // <--- This redirects to '/' in case user is logged in
{
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,               
  canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
}
```

this is your home component html(home.component.html)

```html
<app-admin *ngIf="user_role==='admin'"></app-admin>
<app-user *ngIf="user_role==='user'"></app-user>
```

make sure you are assigning user_role in your typescript file of home component

this is your admin component html(admin.component.html)

```html
<div>
this is admin component
</div>
```

this is your user component html(user.component.html)

```html
<div>
    this is user component
</div>
```

Hope, This will help you.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you can't have two routes with the same path. The easiest change you can make is to change the path to something like this:

```
   {
      path: 'admin',
      component: AdminComponent 
    },
    {
      path: 'user',
      component: UserComponent
    }
```

This is probably the best option because since you want your components to be different based on the user role. You might also want other components to be different and you can do that easily by adding children to the admin or the user routes.

In your AuthGuard you still only return true, but you make two other guards for the admin and user routes. Which check if the user is or isn't the admin.

And you redirect to the correct route by checking the user role once he loges in and then in the component you do `router.navigate(['/admin'])` or `router.navigate(['/user'])`

Comment: correct, this seems like the only solution right now. But it would be awesome if there is some solution that changes component without changing the url

Comment: I'm not really sure about that. I think one page should always have the same component. If you think about it it's counterintuitive for users to see a different page on the same url. I guess in your case it's not really a problem since you have two completely separate areas  based on the user role, but in most situations it shouldn't really be done like that.